# When a user is banned it echo's the wrong notice out

Tags: php, echo

When the user is banned it should echo out the banned echo but instead it echo's out the Failed login echo, Somewhere along the line I've messed something up if someone could assist me with this much appreciated.

My PHP Code Below.

```
<?php
          if (!($user -> LoggedIn()))
          {
            if (isset($_POST['logINBoss']))
                    {
                        $captcha = htmlspecialchars($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]);
                        $secret = $odb->query("SELECT `google_secret` FROM `admin` LIMIT 1")->fetchColumn(0);
                        $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secret."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
                        $response = json_decode($response);
                        if (!$captcha || $response->success == false)
                        {
                        echo '<center><div class="alert alert-icon alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><i class="mdi mdi-check-all"></i>Invalid Captcha Code Entered!</div></center>';
                        } else {
                        $username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']); 
                        $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);
              $Errors = array();
              if (!ctype_alnum($username) || strlen($username) < 1 || strlen($username) > 15)
              {
                $Errors[] = '<center><div class="alert alert-icon alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><i class="mdi mdi-check-all"></i>Username Must Be  Alphanumberic And 4-15 characters in length</div></center>';
              }
              if (empty($username) || empty($password))
              {
                $Errors[] = '<center><div class="alert alert-icon alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><i class="mdi mdi-check-all"></i>Fill in all fields</div></center>';
              }
              if (empty($Errors))
              {
        $SQLCheckLogin = $odb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username AND `password` = :password");
        $SQLCheckLogin -> execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => SHA1($password)));
        $countLogin = $SQLCheckLogin -> fetchColumn(0);
        if ($countLogin == 1)
        {
            $SQLGetInfo = $odb->prepare("SELECT `username`, `ID`, `status` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username AND `password` = :password");
            $SQLGetInfo -> execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => SHA1($password)));
            $userInfo = $SQLGetInfo -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if ($countLogin == 1)
        {
        $SQL = $odb->prepare("SELECT `status` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username");
        $SQL->execute(array(':username' => $username));
        $status = $SQL->fetchColumn(0);
        if($status == 1)
        {
        $SQL = $odb->prepare("SELECT `reason` FROM `bans` WHERE `username` = :username");
        $SQL->execute(array(':username' => $username));
        $ban = $SQL->fetchColumn(0);
        die('<span style="color:red;">You are banned. Reason:</span> ' . htmlspecialchars($ban)); 
        }
                $logAddr = $odb->prepare("INSERT INTO `loginip` (`username`,`ip`,`date`,`http_agent`) VALUES (:user, :ip, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()), :agent);");
                $logAddr->execute(array( ":user" => $username, ":ip" => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], ":agent" => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']));
                $_SESSION['username'] = $userInfo['username'];
                $_SESSION['ID'] = $userInfo['ID'];
                echo '<center><div class="alert alert-icon alert-success alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><i class="mdi mdi-check-all"></i>You have been logged in successfully..</div></center><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=index.php">';
                  }
                  else
                  {
                  echo '<center><div class="alert alert-icon alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><i class="mdi mdi-check-all"></i>You are banned for Reason...</div></center>';        
                  }
                  }
                else
                {
                  echo '<center><div class="alert alert-icon alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><i class="mdi mdi-check-all"></i>Login Failed!!</div></center>';
                }
              }
              else
              {
                  echo '';
                foreach($Errors as $Error)
                {
                  echo ''.htmlspecialchars($Error).'';
                }
                echo '</div>';
              }
            }
          }
          }
          ?>
```

it should echo this

```
                      echo '<center><div class="alert alert-icon alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><i class="mdi mdi-check-all"></i>You are banned for Reason...</div></center>';
```

for a banned user.

but instead it echo's this i don't know why.

```
 echo '<center><div class="alert alert-icon alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><i class="mdi mdi-check-all"></i>Login Failed!!</div></center>';
```

but is there anyone who can see the issue help or even navigate me on correcting it.

Comment: what is status 0 and status 1?

Comment: 1= banned 0 = unabanned.

Comment: you are checking countlogin twice but it fails in second if condition. ithink user might not exist

Comment: That's fine i see that but its different things problem is both echo's i need it to show banned echo if user is banned but it shows failed login echo...

Comment: i will post soon. did you checked that if condition satisfies .first one countlogin

Comment: I've tried that still no luck still trying other ways as we speak I've tried everything it just wont echo the banned echo line

Answer (score 0):

I think it must be

```
if ($status[0] == 1) {
// code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

place this line outside `if` block

```
$SQL = $odb->prepare("SELECT `status` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username");
        $SQL->execute(array(':username' => $username));
        $status = $SQL->fetchColumn(0);
```

and in else part whaich says login failed do this

```
else // else for login failed
{

if($status == 1)
        {
        $SQL = $odb->prepare("SELECT `reason` FROM `bans` WHERE `username` = :username");
        $SQL->execute(array(':username' => $username));
        $ban = $SQL->fetchColumn(0);
echo '<center><div class="alert alert-icon alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><i class="mdi mdi-check-all"></i>You are banned for Reason...</div></center>';        
        die('<span style="color:red;">You are banned. Reason:</span> ' . htmlspecialchars($ban)); 
        }  

                  echo '<center><div class="alert alert-icon alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><i class="mdi mdi-check-all"></i>Login Failed!!</div></center>';
                }
```

you also tried to print that **banned** for valid users too